# How to capitalize a name?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to format names to be capitalized, but only if the word contains more than 3 characters.

Examples:

```
maria da silva => Maria da Silva 
joão carlos otávio => João Carlos Otávio
```

Is it possible to do this customization only with css or would js be necessary?

Comment: In english please.

Comment: Yeah, JS would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JS function like this:

```js
function formatName(fullName = '') {
    return fullName.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-zÀ-ú]+/gi, name => {
        if (name.length <= 3) {
            return name
        }
        return name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)
    })
}

console.log(formatName('mariA da silva'))
console.log(formatName('carlos otáviO'))
console.log(formatName("átila d'lazaro"))
console.log(formatName("rui dos santos"))
```

The above function uses [this `/[a-zÀ-ú]+/gi` regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/xBdJAC/1) to find each name and then apply your logic to each name accordingly.

---

Another approach to avoid messings with names like `"Rui"` and  `"D'Lazaro"` is to create a exclusion-list like:

```
const exclude = ['do', 'dos', 'de', 'da', 'das'];
```

and then:

```
name => {
    if (exclude.some(x => x === name)) {
        return name;
    }
    return name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS would be necessary.

Something like,

```
let str = 'joão carlos otávio'
let strArr = str.split(' ')

for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if (strArr[i].length > 3) {
        strArr[i] = strArr[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].slice(1)
    }
}

let capitalizedString = strArr.join(' ')
```